# GWT migration from 2.6.1 to 2.7 compilation error at asm library

Tags: java, spring, gwt, migration

I am currently migrating GWT to higher version (from 2.6.1 to 2.7).
My app is a mutlimodule maven build on top of stack like: hibernate, spring, gwt.
I've done already a lot of stuff to make it work. Now I struggle with asm library, base on error:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8192
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
```

I've done already a lot of exclusion of asm from spring.
Here is the asm occurence in dependency tree:

```
+- com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.7.0:provided
|  +- (org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:provided - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:provided
|  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:provided
|  |     \- (org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:provided - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:provided
|     \- (org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:provided - omitted for duplicate)
\- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
```

I don't know where this error comes. Here is whole stack trace:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HenixWAR 2.50.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.gwt:gwt-vl:jar:2.0b is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ HenixWAR ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Henix2\workspace\HenixWAR\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (add-source) @ HenixWAR ---
[INFO] Source directory: C:\Henix2\workspace\HenixWAR\target\filtered-sources\java added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HenixWAR ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to ../../src/main/webapp
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to ../../src/main/java/pl/com/casus/Henix/resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to ../../target/spring-resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ HenixWAR ---
[INFO] Compiling 2849 source files to C:\Henix2\workspace\HenixWAR\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ HenixWAR ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Henix2\workspace\HenixWAR\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HenixWAR ---
[INFO] Compiling 424 source files to C:\Henix2\workspace\HenixWAR\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) @ HenixWAR ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) @ HenixWAR ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [pl.com.casus.Henix.modules.main.Main, pl.com.casus.Henix.resources.MavenFilteredUserAgent, pl.com.casus.Henix.resources.Resources, pl.com.casus.Henix.modules.library.Library, MavenFilteredUserAgent]
[INFO] pl.com.casus.Henix.resources.MavenFilteredUserAgent has no EntryPoint - compilation skipped
[INFO] pl.com.casus.Henix.resources.Resources has no EntryPoint - compilation skipped
[INFO] pl.com.casus.Henix.modules.library.Library has no EntryPoint - compilation skipped
[INFO] MavenFilteredUserAgent has no EntryPoint - compilation skipped
[ERROR] wrz 14, 2017 8:28:52 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
[ERROR] WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[INFO] Loading inherited module 'pl.com.casus.Henix.modules.main.Main'
[INFO]    [WARN] Line 4: Setting configuration property named 'UiBinder.useSafeHtmlTemplates' in module 'pl.com.casus.Henix.modules.main.Main' that has not been previously defined
[INFO]    Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.User'
[INFO]       Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.media.Media'
[INFO]          Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.UI'
[INFO]             Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder'
[INFO]                [WARN] Definition of already set configuration property named UiBinder.useSafeHtmlTemplates in com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder (set in pl.com.casus.Henix.modules.main.Main).  This may be disallowed in the future.
[INFO] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8192
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.visitCompileDependenciesInBytecode(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:228)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.getCompileDependencySignature(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:209)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.getSignatureHash(CompiledClass.java:166)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:42)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:37)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies.resolve(Dependencies.java:114)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:366)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:580)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:513)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:499)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:668)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Henix .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.257 s]
[INFO] HenixDAO ........................................... SUCCESS [ 14.418 s]
[INFO] HenixApp ........................................... SUCCESS [ 13.549 s]
[INFO] HenixWS ............................................ SUCCESS [  2.079 s]
[INFO] HenixWAR ........................................... FAILURE [ 42.005 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-14T08:29:06+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 145M/975M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) on project HenixWAR: Command [[
```

And more detailed build:

```
Translatable source found in...
[INFO] Persistent unit cache dir set to: C:\Henix2\workspace\HenixWAR\src\main\gwt-unitCache
[INFO] Looking for previously cached Compilation Units in C:\Henix2\workspace\HenixWAR\src\main\gwt-unitCache
[INFO] Compiling module pl.com.tartus.Henix.modules.main.Main
[INFO]    Looking for precompiled archives.  To disable, use -Dgwt.usearchives=false
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/User.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/regexp/RegExp.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/event/Event.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/UI.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/UserAgent.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/DOM.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/RemoteService.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/activity/Activity.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/place/Place.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/logging/LoggingDisabled.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/json/JSON.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/korbeda/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/xml/XML.gwtar
[INFO]    Found 3017 cached/archived units.  Used 3017 / 6194 units from cache.
[INFO]    Compiling...
[INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
[INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
[INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
[INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
[INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
[INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
[INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
[INFO]       70% complete (ETR: 2 seconds)
[INFO]       80% complete (ETR: 1 seconds)
[INFO]       90% complete (ETR: 1 seconds)
[INFO]       100% complete (ETR: 0 seconds)
[INFO]       Compilation completed in 9,81 seconds
[INFO] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8960
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.visitCompileDependenciesInBytecode(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:228)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.getCompileDependencySignature(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:209)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.getSignatureHash(CompiledClass.java:166)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:42)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:37)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies.resolve(Dependencies.java:114)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:366)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:580)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:513)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:499)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:668)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
[INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

Comment: maybe it can be a classloading issue... in your pom did you try to set GWT classes as the first ones to be used during the compilation?

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: It's long time I don't use GWT but in my last project I had to use this property `gwtSdkFirstInClasspath` in my pom in order to set the GWT sdk as the first in classpath. More details here https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#gwtSdkFirstInClasspath

Comment: Tried. Did not helped